# How do i parse raw data from Flask's request.get_data() to Chinese characters?

Tags: python, http, flask, request

I'm using Flask to build a web server handling some Chinese requests via POST method. Originally, I'm thinking of using `request.form['body']` to get the content, however, because of the client-side encoding is in `BIG5`, somehow returned values from `Flask.request.form` is always decoded using `UTF-8`, so i have to use `request.get_data()` to retrieve raw data from the request and decode it myself.

But the weird thing is that when the `enctype = multipart/form-data` everything is fine that i can use `request.get_data().decode('big5')` to get the correct characters, but when i don't specified enctype which will use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, the returned value like below:

> Result 1.

```
%B6W%C3%D9%A4u%B5%7B%A6%B3%AD%AD%A4%BD%A5q
```

which is not 'BIG5' encoded, the original text should look like below:

> Result 2.

```
超贊工程有限公司
```

'BIG5' encoded one should like below:

> Result 3.

```
xb6W\xc3\xd9\xa4u\xb5{\xa6\xb3\xad\xad\xa4\xbd\xa5q
```

My question is how can i properly decode form data from Result1 to Result2 when using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Code and result if content-type eqauls to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as below:
[image]

Code and result if content-type eqauls to `multipart/form-data` as below:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an URL-encoded string.  Use `urllib` to decode it:

```py
import urllib
data = '%B6W%C3%D9%A4u%B5%7B%A6%B3%AD%AD%A4%BD%A5q'
print(urllib.parse.unquote(data, encoding='big5'))
```

This prints `超贊工程有限公司`, which looks like your expected output.

Comment: Solved, thank u very much!! btw, do u know if there is any way i can specify the encoding when using `request.form['body']` to get data? then i won't have to extract raw data from `request.get_data()`.